# Is there a way to use editorwindow and store a copied component to memory(clipboard)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditorInternal;

public class EditorWindowCopyComponentsData : EditorWindow
{
    static Component[] storedComponents;

    [MenuItem("SmartCopy/ Copy all Components")]
    private static void CopyAllComponents()
    {
        if (Selection.gameObjects.Length != 0)
        {
            storedComponents = Selection.activeGameObject.GetComponents<Component>();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Please select GameObject to copy components from.");
        }
    }

    [MenuItem("SmartCopy/ Paste all Components")]
    private static void PasteAllComponents()
    {
        if (Selection.gameObjects.Length != 0)
        {
            if (storedComponents != null)
            {
                foreach (GameObject targetObject in Selection.gameObjects)
                {
                    foreach (Component targetComponent in storedComponents)
                    {
                        ComponentUtility.CopyComponent(targetComponent);
                        ComponentUtility.PasteComponentAsNew(targetObject);
                    }
                }
                return;
            }

            Debug.Log("No Component to copy.");
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log("No GameObject Selected to paste Components.");
    }

    [MenuItem("SmartCopy/ Delete all Components")]
    private static void DeleteAllComponents()
    {
        foreach (Component targetComponent in Selection.activeGameObject.GetComponents<Component>())
        {
            DestroyImmediate(targetComponent);
        }
    }

    [MenuItem("SmartCopy/ Paste Difference")]
    private static void CopyDifference()
    {
        Debug.Log("Under Construction=====");
    }

    private static bool FillerFunc(Component c)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I don't want to copy the gameobject from the hierarchy but the components on the gameobject.
This is working fine in the same project but is there a way to store the component/s also in some memory buffer maybe the clipboard and use the script in another project to copy the component/s on another gameobject in the other project ?

Maybe there is a need to create/add first the components in the other project and then make the copy not really sure.

Or maybe to write to a text file the stored components names and then each component settings and values and then read the info in the other project and create the components by names and write the settings and values to the component/s ?

The idea is to copy component/s or component/s values between projects.

Screenshot :

[image: Copy component]

Comment: `use the script in another project` I don't think so! In another project the same script might get a different UUID assigned so Unity would not identify it as the "same" component - I might be wrong though. Also how would you make sure that the according components actually exist in the target project? I think you would be way better simply using the already existing way: [`AssetPackages`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html) you can simply export and import an entire prefab including all related assets and scripts.

Comment: A similar approach would be [`AssetBundles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) which may not introduce new types but can have them attached if they already exist in the project

Comment: You can disable `Include references` and only export the stuff you have selected and nothing more ...

Comment: I added a screenshot to my question. It seems to me a bit strange that you can make Copy Component including all settings values of the properties but only in the same project. If you can make Copy Component why not making also that you can copy the component properties settings values to the memory and paste it anywhere else in windows ?

Comment: You mean basically you want [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/clipboard-lite-copy-n-paste-multiple-components-54863) but not be limited to the same project, right? Again I guess the issue will be that this uses references linked to UUIDs of your assets and scripts ... you can try to somehow export a file of it but ... basically this would be what the UnityPackage already does for you ;)

Comment: @derHugo right this is what I mean shingo solution is almost working.

Comment: well yes ... shingo's solution uses JSON while UnityPackage and Unity asset serialization in general uses [YAML](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/YAMLSceneExample.html) ;) but basically it is doing the same thing as already said ... UnityPackage additionally makes sure that the according script files actually also exist in the target project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EditorJsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorJsonUtility.html) to serialize & deserialize components.

Make sure the guid property of the assets are same between projects, otherwise the reference will be broken after pasting.

Copy:

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/Copy Components", false, 20)]
public static void CopyComponents(MenuCommand command)
{
    var go = command.context as GameObject;
    var components = go.GetComponents<Component>();
    var serializedData = new string[components.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
        // Type-AssemblyQualifiedName : Json-Serialized-Data
        serializedData[i] = components[i].GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName + ":" + EditorJsonUtility.ToJson(components[i]);
    EditorGUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer = string.Join("\n", serializedData);
}
```

Paste:

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/Paste Components", false, 21)]
public static void PasteComponents(MenuCommand command)
{
    var go = command.context as GameObject;
    var serializedData = EditorGUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer.Split('\n');
    char[] splitter = { ':' };
    foreach (var data in serializedData)
    {
        var typeAndJson = data.Split(splitter, 2);
        var type = Type.GetType(typeAndJson[0]);
        if (type.FullName == "UnityEngine.Transform") // only 1 transform
            EditorJsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(typeAndJson[1], go.transform);
        else
            EditorJsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(typeAndJson[1], go.AddComponent(type));
    }
}
```

---

Hidden child of a vcam:

[image: hidden child]

Comment: How do I check the guid property ? It does copy and paste but when paste it's without the values settings. Only the Priority property value 27 in this case copied and paste fine but the others not it's just added in the other project empty component. Same component type but empty.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. What is "the Priority property"? I tested for a camera with a transform and a light compoent and it works well, you my check the text in the clipboard to ensure all the data are collectly serialized.

Comment: I tried on vcam (Cinemachine Virtual Camera) to copy the properties and values like in my question bottom last screenshot.  I will check the text.

Comment: For example if you look at the screenshot there is a Body part Follow Offset X -0.08864 or X Damping 1 when I click the GameObject > Copy Components in the editor then I paste it to empty text file in notepad and I can't see the Body and Aim and others.  This link is example of copied content of the virtual camera : https://pastebin.com/kV6aY1Ws

Comment: I changed a bit the code instead var go = command.context as GameObject; I did var components = Selection.activeGameObject.GetComponents<Component>(); for the copy and for the paste var go = Selection.activeGameObject;

Comment: I tested it now also with a Camera and a Light component and it's working fine. But I needed it for Cinemachine Virtual Camera to copy the components/properties and values and it's not working on that.

Comment: @DanielLip Cinemachine components are a bit complicated, they store some data (eg. Body, Aim... in the inspector) in their hidden child components (by change the hideFlags field, I'll upload an image to show that) and show all data in the root component. So if you need to copy a vcam, you need writing more code to copy the children too.

Comment: I understand the child component problem. Not sure how to use the flags, does it binding flags ?  Couldn't find how to do it by google. I will keep trying.

Comment: Not need to use [the flags](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideFlags.html), I just want to tell there is a hidden GameObject. You can get it by using `Transform.GetChild(0)`.